# Como pegar variáveis ​com nome repetidos no método ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, formulário

Vamos la, tenho um método AJAX que pega valores de um formulário e salva na sessão. Existem vários formulários com os mesmos campos, eles são gerados automaticamente conforme um banco de dados, então não posso usar "opcoes 1", "opcoes 2", etc. Então estou usando "opcoes[]" para obter um array au enviar o formulário.

Ao pegar os valores de inputs que não são repetidos no formulário não tenho problema. Porém, ao tentar pegar os valores desses campos com nome "opcoes[]", apenas obtenho os valores do primeiro formulário.

### O formulário, resumidamente, é assim:

```
<?php foreach($produtos as $key => $valueProdutos) { ?>
  <form class="formulario_produto" method="post" action="crud.php">
    <input type="text" name="nome" value="$valueProdutos['nome']">
    <input type="number" name="preco" value="$valueProdutos['preco']>
    <?php foreach($valueProdutos['opcoes'] as $key => $valueOpcoes) { ?>
      <input type="text" name="opcoes[]" value="$valueOpcoes['valor']">
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
<?php } ?>
```

### O AJAX:

```
$('body').on('submit', '.formulario_produto', function submitCB(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const adicionar = "1";
  const nome = $("[name='nome']", this).val();
  const preco = $("[name='preco']", this).val();
  const observacoes = $("[name='observacoes']", this).val();
 // Aqui está o local em que pego as informações das variáveis
  $("[name='opcoes[]']", this).each( function() {
    opcoes.push(this.value);
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: 'crud.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      adicionar: adicionar,
      nome: nome,
      preco: preco,
      opcoes: opcoes
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $('#carrinho').html(response);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
});
```

### E no arquivo crud.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['adicionar'])){
  $nome = $_POST['nome'];
  $preco = $_POST['preco'];
  $opcoes = $_POST['opcoes'];
  echo $nome." - R$".$preco." - ";
  foreach ($opcoes as $key => $valueOpcoes ) {
    echo $valueOpcoes;
  }
}
```

O problema é que obtenho sempre os valores do primeiro formulário, e quero obter só do formulário enviado

Comment: Tira esse this daqui $("[name='opcoes[]']", this). Tá bem  desorganizado seu code diga-se de passagem. Qual a finalidade de n forms se vai enviar tudo via ajax?

Comment: Cara, não enviarei todos os formulários de uma vez, apenas o que eu comandar. Quanto ao "this", coloquei para que pegasse apenas os que estivessem destro do determinado formulário. Já quanto a organização do código, este não é o próprio, é apenas uma transcrição do problema para que se possa entender. Nesse caso, ainda assim removo o "this"?

Comment: Dá uma lida https://stackoverflow.com/q/34028678/4623423 . O post trata de um problema similar

Comment: Obrigado, parece que resolveu